# Is it allowed to repeat a salat?

Tags: salat

السلام عليكم و رحمة الله و بركاته

If we're praying(salat) and trying to maintain khushu' during it, but still thoughts of other things creep in, so because of this, can the salat be repeated? is it permissible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are different opinions on if repeating the *salat* is necessary when *khushu'* is lacking, there is no reason not to repeat it.  There's even a hadith wherein the prophet told a man to join a congregational prayer even though he had already prayed that prayer at home.

In general (excepting forbidden times and places) one should *never* feel discouraged from performing extra *salat*.

Comment: Your answer is at cross-purposes with the question - the _hadith_ you cite makes no mention of whether the man was _repeating_ the prayer, or merely joining the congregation with a voluntary intention (more likely). Your final sentence  is more general and talks about extra _salah_, but not _repeating_ a particular _salah_. I suspect in fact that repeating _salah_ is not recommended, if not forbidden due to 1) opening the door for _waswasa_ from Shaitan 2) the obligation has been discharged (assuming all pillars have been completed), you can't discharge it "again." You can of course pray more.

Comment: In fact, this hadith supports my assertion: http://sunnah.com/abudawud/2/185 . And this one: http://sunnah.com/abudawud/2/189 . Will make these into an answer once I find more info inshaAllah.